# Register specific form type in Syfmony - Compiler Pass

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a specific formType: `OrganizationsType`. This type takes 3 parameters in the constructor. The tokenStorage (`TokenStorageInterface`), the Router(`Router`) and an interface object from my class (`PreparatorInterface`). This form is inside a bundle and I want everyone to create his own `Preparator` by implementing `PreparatorInterface`.

So I wanted to create a Compiler pass that could register this FormType with all parameters. I try this :

```
$organizationListPreparator = $container->findTaggedServiceIds(self::TAG);

    if (empty($organizationListPreparator)) {
        throw new \Exception('CoffreoProOrganizationSelectorBundle need a preparator. Check README.');
    }

$container->register(OrganizationsForm::class, OrganizationsForm::class)
        ->addArgument(new Reference('security.token_storage'))
        ->addArgument(new Reference(key($organizationListPreparator)))
        ->addArgument(new Reference('router'))
        ->setAutoconfigured(true)
        ->setAutowired(true)
        ->setAbstract(true)
        ->addTag('form.type');
```

But when I try to instantiate a form like that

```
$organizationsForm = $this->createForm(OrganizationsForm::class);
```

How can i do something like that?

### Edit

I receive this error message :

```
Too few arguments to function OrganizationSelectorBundle\Form\OrganizationsForm::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/myProject/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on line 92 and exactly 3 expected

[2018-12-18 16:34:38] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Too few arguments to function OrganizationSelectorBundle\Form\OrganizationsForm::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/myProject/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on line 92 and exactly 3 expected" at /var/www/myProject/vendor/organization-selector-bundle/Form/OrganizationsForm.php line 58 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Too few arguments to function OrganizationSelectorBundle\\Form\\OrganizationsForm::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/myProject/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on line 92 and exactly 3 expected at /var/www/myProject/vendor/organization-selector-bundle/Form/OrganizationsForm.php:58)"} []
```

### Edit

When i launch `bin/console deb:container OrganizationForm`

## Information for Service "OrganizationSelectorBundle\Form\OrganizationsForm"

---

Option           Value

---

Service ID       OrganizationSelectorBundle\Form\OrganizationsForm
  Class            OrganizationSelectorBundle\Form\OrganizationsForm
  Tags             form.type
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes

---

I pass in my compiler pass when i add dump('Did I pass here'); die();

When i launch `bin/console debug:container --tag form.type` to list all services with tag `form.type`

```
Symfony Container Services Tagged with "form.type" Tag
======================================================

 --------------------------------------------------------------- ------- --------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID                                                      alias   Class name                                                     
 --------------------------------------------------------------- ------- --------------------------------------------------------------- 
  App\Form\StaffingCustomerType     App\Form\StaffingCustomerType                                  
  App\Form\UserType                 App\Form\UserType                                              
 OrganizationSelectorBundle\Form\OrganizationsForm      OrganizationSelectorBundle\Form\OrganizationsForm           
 --------------------------------------------------------------- ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Consider updating your question with the relevant portion of your error message (if any).  Did you already exclude OrganizationsForm from autowire?  Why are you making it abstract?  Seems like you don't need this at all as long as your require "everyone" to alias PreparatorInterface.

Comment: Good.  Now verify you don't have a OrganizationsForm service using "bin/console debug:container" and verify your compiler pass code is being called with a simple die statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution than use CompilerPass.

I use directly a service definition in yaml and pass as second argument an specific service if. Then i provide a default service for this service id by using alias:

```
OrganizationSelectorBundle\Form\OrganizationsForm:
    arguments:
      - '@security.token_storage'
      - '@coffreo_organization_bundle.organization_list_preparator'
      - '@router'
    tags: [form.type]
    public: false

coffreo_organization_bundle.organization_list_preparator:
    class: Coffreo\Pro\OrganizationSelectorBundle\Preparator\AllOrganizationListPreparator
    arguments: ['@translator']
    public: false
```